# how to make a code that does 2 processes in python

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, process, mainloop

i made a messenger that works with the socket library. it has 2 sides : server and client.
i later decided to make a GUI for it , too. ( with tkinter )
when i was making it , i realized that programs does not work correctly. here :

```
import socket
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
win.geometry("300x300")
win.resizable(False,False)


def disc() :
    s = socket.socket()
    ip = "0.0.0.0"
    port = 9999
    s.bind((ip,port))
    s.listen()
    print ('please wait...')
    c , addr =s.accept()
    print ('someone has joined!')


    while True :
        msg = input('your message : ' )
        c.send(msg.encode('utf8'))
        print (c.recv(1024).decode())

lbl_1 = Label(win,text="mychat",bg="light blue")
lbl_1.place(x=130,y=20)

lbl_2 = Label(win,text="your message: ")
lbl_2.place(x=130,y=50)


lbl_3 = Label(win,text="recieved message: ")
lbl_3.place(x=130,y=70)

btn_1 = Button(win,text="make your device discoverable",command=disc)
btn_1.pack()

txt_1 = Text(win)
txt_1.pack()

word = "messages"
txt_1.insert(END, word)

win.mainloop()
```

here , you can see what i've tried. i have two parts : the socket part and the gui part.
the socket part is in the def block.
but this does not work correctly. if you put the mainloop before socket part , it will never be executed because mainloop is not finished until i close the program.

if you put main loop after socket part , the GUI will not be displayed until someone join the server.(because socket part is not finished)

here , you see i've tried another thing. i put the socket part in def and then made a button for it. but this doesn't work either. when you press the button , the program stops and gives a ( not responding ) error on title bar . ( so until someone has joined , it will not respond. )

i want a solution for this code that the GUI part works and doesn't care to socket part(dismissing it). in other words , python executes the 2 parts in one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to start using [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

You basically have two "while True" loops, the first is the `win.mainloop()` that stops executing when the user exists the GUI. The second is the `while True` in the `disc` function, that waits for input from the user (`msg = input(...)`) and then waits for data from the client (`s.recv`)

```py
import threading

def disc():
    ...

connection = threading.Thread(target=disc).start()
```

The rest of the GUI code goes below the `connection` thread without the `make your device discoverable` part as it is now unnecessary:

```py
# remove this part
btn_1 = Button(win,text="make your device discoverable",command=disc)
btn_1.pack()
```

Comment: thanks! it solved my problem. i searched up on threading and subprocessing and looks like it's a big subject in programming